# Query with subselect fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

this seems like a pretty simple query, but it's failing

```
select LinkContent, 
CASE WHEN LEN(LinkName)>0 THEN
    LinkName
ELSE
   (SELECT LinkName FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] n2 
   WHERE LinkName IS NOT NULL AND n2.LinkContent = n.LinkContent)
END as LinkName
FROM [Newsletter Link Ranking Past month] n
```

Can anyone help? It works with no subselect, so somehow that seems to be the problem, but I know you can do subselects inside of CASE statements so I'm not sure what's happening. Even when I simplify the subselect and take out the where clause it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Try running the sub query on its own ... does it return any values?

Comment: Thanks I ended up going in a completely different direction, but got it figured out @Data_Kid

Comment: Do you mind sharing your answer so the community can learn from it?

Comment: I would, but it's so different from this query, I don't see how it relates. The other one is just a simple counting query. This weird join thing I was trying to do here is not even present in the other one, so I feel like it's irrelevant....